# Can the eclipse debugging id be used for referencing an object in the Display view?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When debugging java applications I sometimes would like to call methods on an object that is contained in a complex structure (like getting the second element of an Iterator on a object in a `HashMap`). While manually folding this out in the `Display` view is certainly possible it is also cumbersome.

It often quite easy with the inspect view to find the internal debugging id of the object I want to examine, and I am therefor wondering if this can be used to reference the object directly? Perhaps something like: `($2235).myMethod()`.

Is this functionality available in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `toString()` method of your objects to get a human friendly view.

However, for existing objects like `HashMap`, you have to unfold its internal structure.